# How to install fink when behind proxy?

Tags: macos, macports, fink

I'm having a Mac computer at work, and the internet connection is through HTTP proxy.
I want to install fink (or macports, doesn't really matter), to have all the useful utilities (like mc).

I've set the proxy during fink installation. It has successfully installed, but "fink selfupdate" cannot download using rsync (using cvs it fails too).

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

From rsync man page:

> You may establish the connection via a web proxy by setting the environment variable RSYNC_PROXY to a hostname:port pair pointing to your web proxy. Note that your web proxy's configuration must support proxy connections to port 873.

So I think you should try `RSYNC_PROXY='proxy.address:xxx' fink selfupdate`